# Minimal diagrams of equivalent knots and type III Reidemeister moves

Tags: knot-theory

Knot theory is not my area so sorry if this is a trivially true or trivially false question.  Given equivalent knots K and L and minimal diagrams D(K) and D(L) of K and L, respectively, is it always possible to relate D(K) and D(L) via type III moves only?

Comment: No.  Pick an orientation of $D(K)$ and $D(L)$ arbitrarily.  If the writhes of $D(K)$ and $D(L)$ differ in absolute value, this provides an obstruction to isotopy via type II and III moves (and hence to isotopy via only type III moves).  This works for links as well with the proper definition of writhe (and obstruction).

Comment: You might have to create a fairly large number of additional crossings in any isotopy from one diagram to the other.

Answer (score 1):

It is not always possible.

For example, let $D$ be the usual diagram of the [pretzel knot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pretzel_link) $P(1, c_1, c_2, c_3)$.  Now, $D$ is [flype equivalent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tait_conjectures#Flyping) to the diagram $D'$ of $P(c_1, 1, c_2, c_3)$.  But, if all of the $c_i$ are positive, large, and distinct, then $D$ and $D'$ are not isotopic (even allowing R-infinity moves) and admit no RIII moves.

Comment: Thanks.  I had a feeling this wasn't true.  Is there an "interesting"  class of knots for which this is true?  Define a knot K to be nonincreasing if, given any two knots L and M equivalent to K and any two minimal diagrams D(L) and D(M) of L and M, respectively, D(L) and D(M) can be related via only type III moves.  For instance, the unknot is trivially nonincreasing.

Comment: The alternating knots without flypes all have unique minimal diagrams (up to R-infinity moves) so trivially give such a class of knots.